# href inside javascript

Tags: php, html, flowplayer

I'm trying to construct a table on the right of the page where I pull out all the videos from the server.  I want the users to click a row in the table and it starts to play a video in flowplayer on the left of the page.  The video url is something I pull out of the DB.

```
<?php

    for($i=0;$i<$num_videos;$i++)
    {
?>              
        <tr onclick="DoNav('<?php echo $result_videos[$i]["video_url"]; ?>');">
            <td>
...
```

Here's the javascript:

```
function DoNav(theUrl)
{
  flowplayer("player", "flowplayer/flowplayer-3.2.7.swf", document.location.href = theUrl);
}
```

For whatever reason I can't seem to get flowplayer to work with this div:

```
<div id="player"><img src="recordings/landscape.jpg" width="320" height="240" /></div>
```

It will only prompt you to open or save the video instead of playing in the current window. If anyone knows this issue here that would be appreciated.  At any rate, I know I can get flowplayer working with a href like so:

```
<a 
href="url" 
style="display:block;width:320px;height:240px;" 
id="player"><img src="recordings/landscape.jpg" width="320" height="240" />
</a>
```

But I don't want to put the href in the table as I want that splash image included as well.  Any ideas?

Comment: Not sure if this applies but I know usually when you set the location.href of the document, the window will immediately redirect to that URL. My assumption here would be that it would evaluate the document.location.href = theUrl before calling the flowplayer function which would bypass the actual function itself and redirect to that url instead. Are you seeing any side effects like that?

Comment: that is probably the reason for it asking me to download/save the file.  Answer from @kevingreen also highlights this.  But what can I do as an alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited to improve clarity.

When the function flowplayer("player", "flowplayer/flowplayer-3.2.7.swf", document.location.href = theUrl); Was called the document.location.href was being evluated and caused the browser to go to the theUrl which prompted for file to be downloaded.

Furthermore we found there is some sort of issue updating a  with the  as a child DOM object. This was solved by moving the image to the background of the  using the inline CSS.

JS Code:

```
function DoNav(theUrl)
{
  flowplayer("player", "flowplayer/flowplayer-3.2.7.swf",  theUrl);
}
```

HTML table:

```
<div id="player" style="display:block;width:320px;height:240px;background-image:url(recordings/landscape.jpg)"></div>
```

PHP stayed the same.

Comment: what is an alternative that I can do?

Comment: What created the flowplayer function ? I'm not sure what it's doing exactly. I think you need to create a <embed> tags etc in that DIV, then pass it the SWF.

Comment: Oh wait, I'm an idiot. Flowplayer is a library, and you tagged this accordingly… I'll be back in about an hour with an answer. I need to run off for a bit.

Comment: Ah I see the flowplayer function comes from <script type="text/javascript" src="flowplayer/example/flowplayer-3.2.6.min.js"></script> at the head.  Typical way to embed flowplayer is to call this function at the head then add the code as I have done.  I can get flowplayer to work fine if I use the href and hardcode a real url.  But what I'm trying to do is get the url to populate when the user clicks on the row in the table.

Comment: What's the third parameter you need to pass to flowplayer() ? What value are you trying to get with document.location.href = theUrl ? I'm googling documentation for flowplayer now.

Comment: It is just the url of the video when someone clicks the row.

Comment: Did you try simply 

flowplayer("player", "flowplayer/flowplayer-3.2.7.swf", theUrl)

Comment: do you mean with the div? <div id="player"><img src="recordings/landscape.jpg" width="320" height="240" /></div> Yes, I did try that.  I should note that it does play the video but also asks you to download/save.

Comment: I meant in flower player.document.location.href pulls the current URL. You can set it which forces the browser to a different URL. You're setting that to the videoURL. Why not just pass the video URL straight into the function? Or do you need the current URL for relativity ?

Comment: Just to be clear, I tried this: flowplayer("player", "flowplayer/flowplayer-3.2.7.swf", theUrl) using the div as the placement but still no luck

Comment: Yes, I tried that but still no luck =\  I've had more success with href code but I'm not sure how to use that with my case.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5070/discussion-between-kevingreen-and-tom-pepernic)

Comment: The answer provided by @kevingreen is to use: flowplayer("player", "flowplayer/flowplayer-3.2.7.swf", theUrl); and for the div you can't use an image...why I don't know but we put an image over the div: <div id="player" style="display:block;width:320px;height:240px;background-image:url(recordings/landscape.jpg)"></div>